# How can I update my data automatically without using AJAX or any loop checking method?

Tags: ajax, database, http

I have a data table page that have to be update right after the database is updated.
I am not allowed to use any loop checking method including AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you're able to detect the insertion in database serverside, the usual solution is to use, like StackOverflow does, [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

They allow you to *push* data from the server to the browser with very little overhead, without useless pulling requests and without client-side loops.